# Using several Styles in a chain

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to import from Excel some tabs in a Word document, to do this I used VBA in Excel.

something as this:

```
With SelDOCFile.Find
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute FindText:="\<FLAG\>"
    If .Found Then
     For Bank = 0 To Banks - 1
      SelDOCFile.InsertCaption Label:="Table", Title:=": Bank " & Bank _
         & " [Special" & Bank & "##A]", Position:=wdCaptionPositionAbove, ExcludeLabel:=0
      SelDOCFile.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
      SelDOCFile.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
      SelDOCFile.Font.Size = 10
      SelDOCFile.Font.Bold = True
      SelDOCFile.Font.Italic = False
      SelDOCFile.Font.Name = "Arial"
      SelDOCFile.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
      SelDOCFile.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=6
      SelDOCFile.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
      SelDOCFile.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("SpecialFunc")
     ....
     Next Bank
  End If
End With
```

What I want is to write Title:="Table 1: Bank 0 [Special0##A]" with a different style for text between [], but here code doesn't work as expected.
I get a difference, but the style is not fully applied, only the color, the size ... changes but when in Word I place cursor on the text, it appears in the same style as the rest of the title

Any suggest?
Thanks

Comment: Captions always use the Caption style, which applies to the entire paragraph. If you want captions to be 10pt Arial, edit the Caption style.

Comment: As you are only applying the style SpecialFunc to selected characters it cannot apply paragraph formatting, only Font formatting such as color and size.

Comment: So I can't do it when I create caption but after I won't have problem?

Comment: I've just checked this in O365 and there appears to be a bug when applying a linked style to selected characters via VBA. If you apply a character style it fully applies (i.e. the underlying xml shows the style has been applied), but a linked style only applies its formatting and acts like direct formatting. This applies to any selected text not just a caption.

Comment: By adding Char it works!
`SelDOCFile.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("SpecialFunc Char")`

Comment: There is, however, a bug as the built-in linked styles should apply correctly when using their style enum, e.g. Selection.style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1). Custom linked styles should also apply correctly without using the name of the hidden character style. Glad you found a work around though.